# What alternative battery can I use for a Canon AV-1 film camera?

Tags: canon, film, battery

I got hold of an old Canon AV-1 film camera I want to learn how to use. But looking for a battery for it, a 4LR44, is quite hard. It must probably be because people are using dSLRs with rechargeable batteries nowadays that these film batteries tend to be harder to find.

I want to know if I can instead stack four LR44 batteries into the battery chamber of the Canon AV-1 instead of using one 4LR44 battery.

Answer (score 8):

They really aren't that hard to find -- you're just looking in the wrong place. They're a popular battery for those dog training shock collars as well, and you can get them in 25-packs on [eBay](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=4LR44%20battery&_sacat=See-All-Categories) for under $20 (or singly for about two and a half dollars). You might not find them in every camera store and drugstore anymore, but they're still around in droves.

That said, a 4LR44 is four LR44s. Whether you can use four of the button cells or not depends on the design of the battery compartment -- if the walls are metal and connect with the end cap, then you'd be bypassing all but the first cell (and potentially shorting out the others). If the walls are insulated from the end connectors, then yes, you'll get the right voltage and form factor (but the first cell in will flip over on you just about half of the time).

Comment: Also, different manufacturers often use different numbers for the same battery. For example, the 4LR44 may be PX28, 28L (lithium version), 28A (alkaline), etc. There's usually a cross-reference list somewhere on the package, but in much smaller type than the manufacturer's "main" designation. Example: http://store.batteryspecialists.com/px28a.html

Answer (score 2):

I am way into film photography I have every A series camera they all use the 4LR44 but AL-1. I always buy my batteries in bulk. They are way easy to find I buy mine on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002B8WJPI)

Answer (score 0):

Just get a PX28L (lithium) or PX28A (Alkaline), both works ok on my AV-1. I buy them locally for about 7 dollars each. Enjoy that AV-1, is very similar to the old Nikon EM, both were released about the same time in 1979.

Comment: $7 each is a lot more expensive than ~$0.60 each that you'd pay for a [4LR44](http://www.amazon.com/Alkaline-Batteries-Training-Collars-Loopacell/dp/B00PSNTVV8).